# multiple has_many associations to same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working in a system that will list buys and sells of a product. Since the listings of these buys and sells have the same information - unit_price and quantity - I was thinking about making only 2 models: Item and Listing. But, how do I make 2 has_many associations between the Item and the Listing? I was thinking about polymorphic association, but I couldn't make it work

Migration

```
create_table :listings do |t|
  t.integer :unit_price
  t.integer :quantity
  t.references :listable, polymorphic: true, index: true
  t.timestamps
end
```

item.rb

```
has_many :buys, as: :listable
has_many :sells, as: :listable
```

listing.rb

```
belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
```

I try running this on console and it doesn't work:

```
rails c
Item.create!
Item.first.buys
```

Calls this error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Item::Buy
```

Comment: Polymorphic association works the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Listing` migration:

```
create_table :listings do |t|
  t.integer :unit_price
  t.integer :quantity
  t.integer :item_id
  t.integer :type
  t.timestamps
end
```

Now in the `Item` model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :buys,  -> { where "type = 0" }, class_name: "Listing"
  has_many :sells, -> { where "type = 1" }, class_name: "Listing"
end
```

The `type` field serves as an indication of the listing: the value is `0` for `buys` and `1` for `sells`.